# LTL - Büchi-automaton Translation

Tags: lo.logic, automata-theory

I need some help in Generalized Büchi automaton ..
I do understand the translation of a LTL-formula ϕ into Generalized Büchi automaton A= (Q, Δ, I, F), with F= {F1,...,Fn}

My problem is F .. 
I know that for every until-formula (a_i U b_i) there exist F-i that contains states with b_i or states with "not (a_i U b_i)"

### if there no exists an until-subformula in ϕ? then F is empty !!

But how do i know if a word is accepted or not ??

For example the LTL-Formula  ϕ= Xp with an atomic proposition p.
the generalized Büchi automaton A ist then:
Q= {q1, q2, q3, q4}

q1= {Xp, p};

q2= {not Xp, p};

q3= {XP, not p};

q4= {not Xp, not p};

Δ(q1, p)= { q1, q2 };

Δ(q2, p)= { q3, q4 };

Δ(q3, not p)= { q1, q2 };

Δ(q4, not p)= { q3, q4 };

I= {q1, q3};

### F= {};

how do i know if a word is accepted from A or not ?? 
isn't a word like pppppppppp.... an accepted word ? where i can see that ? 
and why isn't pqppppppp...an accepted run?

thanks!!

Comment: The acceptance condition for generalized Büchi automata is that for every set of states $S\in F$, there exists a state $s\in S$ that occurs infinitely often in the run. If $F$ is empty, this condition is vacuously *true*, hence the automaton accepts every $\omega$-word for which there exists an infinite run (note that the automaton is nondeterministic and $\Delta(q,s)$ may well be empty, hence it may happen that there is no run).

Comment: thank you very much for your fast answer *_* my last question: should the first position of an infinite word accept ϕ? and that's why  "pqppppppp..." isn't an accepted word for my automata A for the formula ϕ= Xp?